# Excel Transpose between files with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to transpose between files but am stuck? When I transpose within only one file, my code works. But when I tried to transpose to another file, it didn't. My syntax is obviously faulty.

I have 80 customer surveys that I hope to transpose into just one.

My code that works is:

```
Sub Trans2()
    Range("C14:C21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                           False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

But when I try and then run it from one workbook and transpose into another one, it fails.

My "broken" code is:

```
Sub TransposeInfo()
    '
    ' Transpose info between files
    '
    Dim mySource As String
    Dim myDest As String
    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook
    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'Define path and filename
    mySource = "C:\2018\CustSvy001.xls*"
    myDest = "C:\2018\CustResults.xlsx"

    'Open files
    Set wbkWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open(mySource)
    Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(myDest)

    'Select items to transpose
    wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("Q8").Range("B8:B11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("New").Range("G6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                           False, Transpose:=True

    'Close the two workbooks
    wbkWorkbook1.Close (True)
    wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? I'm pretty green on VBA so please the less complicated the better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error:

[image: Error Message]

it's because of the `*` in the file name - replace that with the exact letter in your file name

.

Try this:

---

```
Public Sub TransposeInfoBetweenFiles()
    Dim mySource As String
    Dim myDest As String
    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook
    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'Define path and filename
    mySource = "C:\2018\CustSvy001.xlsx" '<- Replaced "*" with "x" or "m"
    myDest = "C:\2018\CustResults.xlsx"  '<- This is Ok (exact path and file name)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open files
    Set wbkWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open(mySource)
    Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(myDest)

    'Select items to transpose
    wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("Q8").Range("B8:B11").Copy
    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("New").Range("G6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                                               SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    'Close the two workbooks
    wbkWorkbook1.Close True
    wbkWorkbook2.Close True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---